# Multiple items passed into a parameter of type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem - build error ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, build-error

This arose after I upgraded the framework of my Web API from netcoreapp7.0 to netcoreapp8.0.

I receive this build error:

"C:\Users\Dewey.nuget\packages;C:\Users\dewey.nuget\packages" is an invalid value for the "SourceRoot" parameter of the "Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".

Here is the contents of the file in which the error occurs, C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub\build\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.targets:

```
<!-- Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements. The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license. See the License.txt file in the project root for more information. -->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_SourceLinkGitHubAssemblyFile Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' != 'Core'">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\net472\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.dll</_SourceLinkGitHubAssemblyFile>
    <_SourceLinkGitHubAssemblyFile Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Core'">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\core\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.dll</_SourceLinkGitHubAssemblyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl" AssemblyFile="$(_SourceLinkGitHubAssemblyFile)"/>
  <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.TranslateRepositoryUrls" AssemblyFile="$(_SourceLinkGitHubAssemblyFile)"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourceLinkUrlInitializerTargets>$(SourceLinkUrlInitializerTargets);_InitializeGitHubSourceLinkUrl</SourceLinkUrlInitializerTargets>
    <SourceControlManagerUrlTranslationTargets>$(SourceControlManagerUrlTranslationTargets);TranslateGitHubUrlsInSourceControlInformation</SourceControlManagerUrlTranslationTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="_InitializeGitHubSourceLinkUrl" Outputs="%(SourceRoot.Identity)">
    <!--
      The task calculates SourceLink URL for a given SourceRoot.

      If the SourceRoot is associated with a git repository with a recognized domain the <see cref="SourceLinkUrl"/>
      output property is set to the content URL corresponding to the domain, otherwise it is set to string "N/A".

      Recognized domains are specified via Hosts (initialized from SourceLinkGitHubHost item group).
      In addition, if SourceLinkHasSingleProvider is true an implicit host is parsed from RepositoryUrl.

      Example of SourceLinkGitHubHost items:

      <ItemGroup>
        <SourceLinkGitHubHost Include="github.com" ContentUrl="https://raw.githubusercontent.com"/>
        <SourceLinkGitHubHost Include="mygithub1.com" />           ContentUrl defaults to https://mygithub1.com/raw
        <SourceLinkGitHubHost Include="mygithub2.com:8080" />      ContentUrl defaults to https://mygithub2.com:8080/raw
      </ItemGroup>

      ContentUrl is optional. If not specified it defaults to "https://{domain}/raw".
    -->
    <Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl RepositoryUrl="$(PrivateRepositoryUrl)" SourceRoot="@(SourceRoot)" Hosts="@(SourceLinkGitHubHost)" IsSingleProvider="$(SourceLinkHasSingleProvider)">
      <Output TaskParameter="SourceLinkUrl" PropertyName="_SourceLinkUrlToUpdate"/>
    </Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl>

    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Only update the SourceLinkUrl metadata if the SourceRoot belongs to this source control -->
      <SourceRoot Update="%(Identity)" SourceLinkUrl="$(_SourceLinkUrlToUpdate)" Condition="'$(_SourceLinkUrlToUpdate)' != 'N/A'"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- 
    We need to translate ssh URLs to https.
  -->
  <Target Name="TranslateGitHubUrlsInSourceControlInformation">

    <ItemGroup>
      <_TranslatedSourceRoot Remove="@(_TranslatedSourceRoot)"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.TranslateRepositoryUrls RepositoryUrl="$(ScmRepositoryUrl)" SourceRoots="@(SourceRoot)" Hosts="@(SourceLinkGitHubHost)" IsSingleProvider="$(SourceLinkHasSingleProvider)">
      <Output TaskParameter="TranslatedRepositoryUrl" PropertyName="ScmRepositoryUrl"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="TranslatedSourceRoots" ItemName="_TranslatedSourceRoot"/>
    </Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.TranslateRepositoryUrls>

    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceRoot Remove="@(SourceRoot)"/>
      <SourceRoot Include="@(_TranslatedSourceRoot)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  
</Target>

</Project>
```

I am not at all familiar with this file...any help is appreciated!

Comment: after searching for `Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem"` error, it looks like many migration would get this issue but none of them is related to .net7 -> .net 8. According to the description, it looks like if we change `C:\Users\Dewey.nuget\packages;C:\Users\dewey.nuget\packages` to `C:\Users\dewey.nuget\packages` the issue would be solved.

Comment: I mean we have this link which described it: https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#multiple-providers-repositories-with-submodules

Comment: I received the solution to my problem in https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/issues/1172.